# #line processor directive in C# increases the line number

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, csc

The `#line` processor directive in C# increases the line number for each line to the end of file or until it reaches another `#line` processor directive; an auto incremental line number.

That was interesting! For example:

```
try
{
#line 110
    act();
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
catch (Exception x) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
```

Shows that an exception happened at line 111 (Not 110!).

Question: Assume that #line shows a line number different from real line number. For example `#line 110` is actually placed at real line number 13. Now is there a way to cancel the functionality of `#line` and show that an exception happened on actual line 23 (not 120)?

Note: I just want to be sure I am not missing anything (or doing anything stupid).

I am working with Visual Studio 2012 on a .NET 4.5 project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `#line default`, which reverts back to the natural line numbering.
See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34dk387t.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`#line N` directive set difference between real line and virtual N line. To restore real line counting use `#line default`.